# Requesting help to parse a string

Tags: powershell

I am using Invoke-WebRequest to get back an HtmlWebResponseObject object. I want to get the value of the ID field, when the description field matches a particular string (in this case, "server1"). There are hundreds of results returned by Invoke-WebRequest (so the string is super long) Given the sample below, how would I extract the ID?

> {
>     "status": 200,
>     "data": [
>       {
>         "nextRecipient": 0,
>         "clearSent": true,
>         "lastSentNotificationOn": 0,
>         "netscanVersion": "0",
>         "suppressAlertClear": "false",
>         "build": "19000",
>         "lastSentNotificationOnLocal": "",
>         "id": 6,
>         "resendIval": 15,
>         "watchdogUpdatedOn": "2016-04-11 10:28:02 MDT",
>         "escalatingChainId": 6,
>         "description": "domain\server1",
>         "ackComment": "",
>         "credential2": "",
>         "updatedOn": 1460392096,
>         "updatedOnLocal": "2016-04-11 10:28:16 MDT",
>         "agentConf": "product.code={guid}\r\n#  Installer version, Shall not be modified\r\ninstaller.version=0001\r\n\r\n# Generated by Agent Configuration Wizard\r\nserver=url\r\ncompany=company\r\nid=6\r\ncredential==cred\r\n\r\n# logger settings. Set logger.size to 0 to no limitation on logger size, otherwise, size limited to Mbytes specified by that\r\nlogger.output=console\r\nlogger.logfile=\r\nlogger.size=64\r\nlogger.level=info\r\n\r\n#watchdog log level\r\nlogger.watchdog=info\r\n# for each component, add more detailed control here\r\n# e.g. \r\n# logger.level.controller=debug\r\n#\r\n# if not set, it will use default log level, i.e. value of logger.level\r\n#\r\n\r\n#if agent shall watch watchdog, default to false\r\nagentmonitorwatchdog=true\r\n\r\n#whether watchdog upgrades agent, default to true\r\nagent.autoupgrade=true\r\n\r\n#service connection timeouts. Default to 5 seconds for connecting and 30 seconds for sending / reading feeds from server\r\nservice.connect_timeout=5\r\nservice.read_timeout=30\r\n\r\n#SSL & Proxy settings\r\nssl.enable=true\r\nproxy.enable=false\r\nproxy.host= \r\nproxy.port=\r\nproxy.user=\r\nproxy.pass=\r\nproxy.exclude=\r\n\r\n#sbproxy settings\r\nsbproxy.address=127.0.0.1\r\nsbproxy.port=72\r\nsbproxy.logsize=64\r\nsbproxy.restartOn102=false\r\nsbproxy.pdhNoAuthentication=false\r\n\r\n#sbproxy connection pool settings\r\nsbproxy.pool.connections=50\r

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the response from a JSON string to an object and expand the relevant properties:

```
$response | ConvertFrom-Json |
  Select-Object -Expand data |
  Where-Object { $_.description -match 'server1' } |
  Select-Object -Expand id
```

Comment: Using the code you posted, I can see all of the IDs, but I only want the ID of "server1".

`$response | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id | Where {$_ -eq '6'}` gives me back just one entry, but I'm only getting back one property. I tried `$response | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty id | Where {$response | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty data | Select-Object -ExpandProperty description | where {$_ -eq "server1"}}`, but that gave me back all of the IDs too. Sorry 4 format

Comment: Filter on the description before expand the id. See updated answer.

Comment: Brilliant! I couldn't figure out where to stick that filter. :)